# Is it okay to use country flags with currencies?

Tags: forms, image, standards, currency

We are considering incorporating national flags into a currency selector, alongside [ISO currency codes](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9105/international-currency-formatting-guidelines-currency-codes), like this:

[image: radio button selections of currencies with flags inline]

We are well aware we [should not use flags for selecting languages](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11891/should-i-use-country-flags-in-language-selection-fields) because there isn't a one to one mapping (and other sensitivities) but we're not aware of the same problems occurring with regard to currencies.

**Is this a naïve question – are there any trips or traps we should be aware of?**

Comment: As long as you use the currency code in addition to the flag it seems fine to me.

Comment: @erics What is your goal? Would it be acceptable to just have the users select country and then give them the currency for that country?

Comment: Goal is to visually expand or explain what the ISO currency code means (they are also coded with ``<abbr title="Swiss Francs">CHF</abbr>``)

Comment: For what it's worth, this way of highlighting currencies is commonplace in currency exchange counters, in countries where that's a thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be fine using flags. If you look at [the list of currencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_circulating_currencies), the names are usually made up of a country name and currency (Singapore dollar, Russian ruble, Swiss franc).

Some places use currency that does not originate form a country. For example, most Caribbean countries use the East Caribbean dollar. The Euro is another example. Using the union flag in those cases will not offend any of the members.

Comment: I've been using [xe.com](http://www.xe.com/) (and watching it develop v. slowly) for maybe a decade or so and they use the same flag/TLA currency association except that they too use the long description (TLA + description) during the currency selection process, and flag+TLA in any tabular display, so I'd agree with this - use the longer description where space permits.

Answer (score 6):

Of course not every country in European Union uses Euro as a currency. I guess though it shouldn't be a problem, as people don't identify themselves with EU flag.

Qualitative test would resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would actually go with the Flag, the actual words for the currency and the 3 letter acronym as they actually get confusing too. Helps with understanding of the place to the currency.

You might want to create a way to link to information that list countries which also take that currency e.g the Euro

Also add help for people to understand if its a closed currency (only available to buy in the country), if you need to.

- USD  : United States Dollar
- EUR  : European Euro
- CHF  : Swiss Franc
- GBP  : Great British Pound
- AUD  : Australian Dollar

Comment: In some of the places we want to do this we are constrained by available space. We do use the ``<abbr>`` markup to add a tooltip.