# Currency format: By Locale or Currency?

Tags: language, formatting, currency

Similar to this, but different question: [International Currency Formatting Guidelines — Currency Codes](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9105/international-currency-formatting-guidelines-currency-codes)

Wondering if currency formats are ***locale*** or ***currency*** dependent. For instance, if I wanted to display USD on a page in the French language (fr_FR), would I write $123.50 or 123,50 $? Similarly, if I wanted to display Euros to a person in English (en_EN) would I write €123.50 or 123,50 €?

I found this showing how euro currency format changes throughout locales: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_issues_concerning_the_euro#Summary

But so far I've only seen a definitive answer for the Euro.

Answer (score 5):

They are neither language nor currency dependent, at least not solely. They are *locale* specific, which is a combination of language and location. So the best UX is to not rely on language alone, but check the user's locale and format the currency according to their preferred formatting. In your example of displaying USD to a French user, check what kind of French first (from France, Canada, Mali, etc?) and use the appropriate formatting for that specific locale. For a French user from France I think that would be 123,50 $

Comment: Are there any references to back this up?

Comment: For such a generic use case it's common sense. To be more precise you would have to be more specific about how the page is used. Who are the users and what are their tasks? Are they shopping for themselves or are they entering receipts? Do they deal with multiple different currencies on the same page or is everything the same?

Comment: @illuminaut Something similar I want to ask. In indonesia people understand `10,000,00.00` as `10.000.00,00`.
So, if a person has locale `id-id`, it should be `10.000.00,00`, but what if its `en-id`? People will understand `10,000,00.00` , but the libraries return `10.000.00,00`.